# Dystopian society that is ruled by a totalitarian government that uses a law that cannot be questioned

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

I read only a small description of the plot some years ago, but got interested immediately, but can't remember the name.
It's about some dystopian society, where the government is super oppressive, and keeps invoking some law/rule/protocol that justifies it, but one of the paragraphs of that same law is that you don't question it, so it is used as a catch-all for everything.

Everything is done by the authorities using that law as reason, but the people cannot ask what the law is about, so it ends up being a null-sum situation. Apparently, after a while, because of this, nobody knows what the law is about.

Does anyone recognize this?

Comment: Catch-22?  The oppressive government is the WWII war machine, so it wouldn't qualfiy as SF in that case.

Comment: yeah, i know about catch 22, but from what I read in the description, that's about a law-loop thingy. This is about an all-catching law that justified all, and everything is done in its name, but nobody knows what it's about.

Comment: Well, in the book it eventually IS used in that way (and they even outright say, while doing various deeeds in its name, something like 'Catch-22 says we don't have to tell you what's in it.'), although it starts out as just a 'catch' that keeps popping up to get you stuck in ridiculous situations.  But fair enough if you're looking for a more obviously SF example.

Comment: hmm. maybe that's it, then... I don't exactly know what I'm looking for, I just remember being interested in these points.